# how to use a 'mouseout' in jquery

Tags: jquery

sorry google translator...
I'm a novice developer. help me!

I would like to implement as shown.
http://blog.naver.com/ikks06luck/220120719586 "click here"

but...
'mouseout', it does not work Properly...
'mini_nav_toggle'div, move it back and forth wildly.

html code is :

```
    <div id="mini_nav_toggle" class="mini_nav_wrap" style="display:none;">
    <div class="mini_nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <button class="mini_nav_list btn btn-primary" onclick="basket();">장바구니/button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="mini_nav_list btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#myModal">위시리스트</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="mini_nav_list btn btn-primary"
                onclick="buy_and_sell();">사고팔기</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="mini_nav_list btn btn-primary"
                onclick="posting_form();">포스팅하기</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="mini_nav_list btn btn-primary">메신저</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="mini_nav_list btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#mySetup">설정</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript code is :

```
    var eventClientX;
$(function(){
    $("div").mousemove(function(event) {
        eventClientX = event.clientX;
        if (eventClientX == 0) {
            $(function(){$('#mini_nav_toggle').show('slide',{direction:'left'},200)});
            return;
        }
    });

    $("#mini_nav_toggle").mouseout(
        function(){$(this).hide('slide',{direction:'left'},200)}
    );
});
```

css code is :

```
  .mini_nav_wrap{
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top:180px;
width:140px;
height:220px;
border-radius:5px;
z-index: 1000;
opacity: 0.8;
background-color: black;
}
.mini_nav {
margin:10px;
}
.mini_nav ul{
display:table;
}
.mini_nav li{
display:table-row;
}

.mini_nav_list {
width: 130px;
border-radius:0;
color:#FFF;
}
```

please help!!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Sorry Google Translator, I cannot read chinese

Comment: try using "mouseleave" instead of mouseout.

Comment: @ZeeTee It's all right...i have to study English hard...haha

Comment: @jamesemanon god...oh my god!!!!!!solved at a time!!!oh....i love you thank you!!!thank you!!!thank you!!!thank you!!!i love you thank you!!!